# Does the transformation of the spherical wave really result in a spherical wave, as Einstein claims in his 1905 paper?

Tags: special-relativity, waves

This question have been closed, without giving any valid reason! The ad hominem attacks made by some users are, however, simply ignored. It seems that decisions are politically motivated, instead of scientifically investigated. So far not one answer have shown how a spherical wave can transform in a spherical wave! Yet, the question must be closed and free discussion stifled.

Fact 1: no user have provided a spreadsheet that shows a circle when freezing time t’ so far!
Fact 2: one user complained about errors in my question, yet could not provide any details when prompted! This is tantamount to harassment.
Fact 3: most users responded with ad hominem attacks and irrational arguments. Is this how you want the general public to view scientists?
Fact 4: It is demonstrated clearly in my answer that you cannot have a sphere for an instant of time t’ as it will lead to a contradiction. No one have refuted this fact so far! Instead someone voted to close the question - they must clearly be getting quite desperate to take such a decision!
Fact 5: no user have provided a graph of a circle or sphere in time t’ so far in an answer! Instead we find story telling, asking everyone to ‘belief’ that an ellipse becomes a circle - because Einstein says it must!

In his 1905 paper Einstein makes the following claim:

https://bit.ly/3thuwdW

According to Einstein, the wave resulting from the transformation equation is also a spherical wave, hence confirming the validity of his postulate of constant speed of light.

But it is easy to verify that the transformed equation does not in fact produce a spherical wave.

As a special case, take Gamma large (implying that v approaches c).

Case 1:
$x=ct $(spherical wave in x axis direction)
Take the limit as ${lim_v \to c}$:
Then $\xi=x’=\gamma  (x-vt)$
$=\gamma (ct-vt)$
$=(c-v)t \frac{1}{\sqrt(1-(v/c)^2)}$

$= (c-v)t  \frac{1}{\sqrt((v^2-c^2)/c^2))}$
$= (c-v)t \frac{1}{\sqrt(((v-c)*(v+c))/c^2))}$
$= -t\frac{\sqrt(v-c)}{\sqrt((v+c)/c^2)})$
${lim_v \to c }$
$\xi=0$

Case 2: $x=-ct$ (spherical wave in x axis direction)
Take the limit as ${lim_v \to c}$:
Then $\xi=x’=\gamma  (x-vt)=\gamma (-c-v)t$
$= -\gamma  (c+v) t$
${lim_v \to c}$
$=-2 \gamma (ct)$

Hence $x=ct$ implies x’=0 and $x=-ct$ implies $x’=-2\gamma  (ct)$
It can be seen that the x axis is stretched (length contracted) by the factor Gamma, whereas the y and z axis are unchanged:$ y’=y=ct$. The x axis also appears shifted to: $-\gamma  (ct).$

From the above it is clear that a scatterplot of y’ versus x’ is not circular, but rather an ellipsoidal shape!
For the general case of motion along the x,y and z axis the resulting shape will be ellipsoidal, not spherical.

The transformed time axis will be:
$\tau=t’=\gamma (t-v/c^2 x)=\gamma (1-v/c)t$
Hence the clock of the moving observer is time dilated (clock retardation).

The transformed Y and Z axis remains unaffected.
The transformed X axis called Ksi is skewed by the transformation (multiplication by Gamma) and hence is no longer spherical (or circular in lower dimensions).

A simple spreadsheet based on [1] confirms that the transformation equation is not a spherical wave, even though the values satisfy the transformation equation:

https://bit.ly/3r8gjgL

A similar plot is obtained by generating 10000 random points on a sphere and making a scatterplot of y’ versus x’:

https://bit.ly/3Gk1gH4

The stretching of the x axis is clearly visible on the right hand side plot above.

The spreadsheet can be found here: https://bit.ly/3Hp5pd3

Hence the spherical wave proof of Einstein fails and the proof that the postulate of the constancy of the speed of light is compatible with relativity also fails.

[1] http://www.stevenbbryant.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Disruptive_PREVIEW.pdfReply [image][image][image]

Comment: Note we use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on this site for mathematical expressions.

Comment: Please use the $\LaTeX$ markup. Your equations are hard to read.

Comment: @robphy Note that LaTex is not the same as Mathjax.  Very similar but differences.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're talking about a paper that has been under the microscope for over a hundred years.  Most likely scenario - you made a mistake (or two).

Comment: I have tried to use latex symbols to improve the readability, but can’t find Ksi that Einstein used in his 1905 paper. Can you help me with the Latex expression?

Comment: The symbol you want is \xi: $\xi$.

Comment: I've had a chance to look at your spreadsheet and can confirm the mistake you have made- see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Obviously it is possible for anyone (except of course Einstein) to make mistakes! I just want to clarify, my question is based on a book [1], it is not something that I made up! If there are mistakes, surely then it would be easy to find them and help me understand things better?

Comment: To improve readability, remove the $\times$ (where are usually unnecessary), use \sqrt with { }  as in $\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}$. Use \lim_{v\to c} .

Comment: Note that the doppler factor $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+(v/c)}{1-(v/c)}}$ arises in your calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Editing my answer to better address the original question.  It is mainly an algebra difficulty, and albeit the math is a bit subtle.

I will show you the algebra Einstein left out in his paper.  I'll go the opposite way starting with the moving frame because the algebra is slightly easier.

$\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2=c^2\tau^2$

Substitute in the Lorentz transformation equations from Sec. 3

$\gamma^2(x-vt)^2+y^2+z^2=c^2\gamma^2(t-vx/c^2)^2$

Multiply out the squared polynomial terms

$\gamma^2(x^2-2xvt+v^2t^2)+y^2+z^2=c^2\gamma^2(t^2-2xvt/c^2+v^2x^2/c^4)$

Distribute $c^2$

$\gamma^2(x^2-2xvt+v^2t^2)+y^2+z^2=\gamma^2(c^2t^2-2xvt+v^2x^2/c^2)$

Cancel two terms, and swap two others to the opposite side of the equation

$\gamma^2(x^2-v^2x^2/c^2)+y^2+z^2=\gamma^2(c^2t^2-v^2t^2)$

Finally, factor out $x^2$ and $c^2t^2$

$\gamma^2x^2(1-v^2/c^2)+y^2+z^2=\gamma^2c^2t^2(1-v^2/c^2)$

and recognize that the remaining expression in parentheses equals $1/\gamma^2$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=c^2t^2$

Q.E.D.

It's pretty cool how this works out and not at all obvious from the start.
Couple of things to note: there is no need to substitute $x=ct$ or $v=c$ and in fact it is incorrect to do so. $v$ is the speed of the moving frame, not the speed of light.   The condition of being a light ray is fulfilled simply by the equation itself, i.e. in any direction $r^2=(ct)^2$.

Comment: “Gamma is not a constant”, obviously not! Where did I say it is a constant? Seems to be a straw man argument.

Comment: You seem to have updated your equations since the first time I reviewed it, but in your Case 2 for example you take the limit as v=c, which makes gamma approach infinity, yet gamma still appears in the expression after this. This is just one of a number of algebraic and logical errors in your analysis. Voting to close the question since you are essentially asking for algebra help in a combative manner, rather than helping illuminate physics concepts

Comment: “You seem to have updated your equations since the first time I reviewed it”,
NO - the equations have NOT been fundamentally changed! Some users seemed to find it difficult to read, so I improved it using Latex. Is there anything wrong with this? Unfortunately you imply that there was something wrong with the equations, hence the change. This is false and misleading.

Comment: “but in your Case 2 for example you take the limit as v=c, which makes gamma approach infinity, yet gamma still appears in the expression after this.”,
This is rather silly, how would you simplify Gamma as v->c?
It is obviously not an error - unless you can supply us with a simpler expression for Gamma?

“This is just one of a number of algebraic and logical errors in your analysis. “,
Such as? Please supply details to backup your claim! Otherwise you are unscientific.

Comment: “Voting to close the question since you are essentially asking for algebra help in a combative manner, rather than helping illuminate physics concepts – “,
See my previous comments: you have not found any errors so far and is simply looking for an excuse not to answer the question. Seems a rather unscientific approach to me- can you not do better than this and actually show why you think I am wrong?

Comment: “Editing my answer to better address the original question. It is mainly an algebra difficulty, and albeit the math is a bit subtle.
I will show you the algebra Einstein left out in his paper.”,

It is indeed interesting, but does not answer the original question!

Answer (score 2):

---

(update 1/21/2022)

[image: robphy-CircularLightClock-VisualizingProperTimeInSpecialRelativity]

Play with my visualization at https://www.geogebra.org/m/pr63mk3j 
(a variant of my https://www.geogebra.org/m/XFXzXGTq , the one linked below)

In special relativity,
the elapsed time according to an inertial observer
can be interpreted with **"a light clock carried by that inertial observer"**, thought of as that observer's wristwatch.  (This is visualized below with **circular light clocks**...  arrangements of light-clocks that extends the "Michelson-Morley apparatus" as a spatially-orthogonal pair of light-clocks)

An "**instant of time T** according to that observer" is a [hyper]plane
that is determined by the **"intersection of two light cones"**, specifically, the future lightcone of a past event (say) 1 sec on his wristwatch before the event when his wristwatch marks time T
and the past lightcone of the future event 1 sec on his wristwatch after that event marking T.

The **set of events** in this **intersection of light cones
 is a circle** (sphere)
**at an instant of time according to this inertial observer.**
Think of these distant events as being measured by "radar measurements" done by an inertial observer.

However, if two inertial observers are in relative motion,
these [hyper]planes do not generally coincide,
and, more importantly, are not parallel.

*(This is the relativity of simultaneity according to special relativity, as many others have said here.)*

The **"circle of events simultaneous to one inertial observer"**

is
"a sequence of **events at different times** according to another observer
that meets the **spatial points of an ellipse at rest** according to that observer", where the foci correspond to the spatial location of the emission event and reception event in this frame.

So, in particular,
the "circle of reflections-events for a moving clock"

is interpreted as

"a set of events at sequential times that trace out an ellipse at rest in the lab frame."

Similarly, in accord with special relativity,
the "circle of reflections-events for the lab clock"

is interpreted as

"a set of events at sequential times that trace out an ellipse at rest in the moving frame."

See the graphics and animations below.

---

([old] UPDATED ADDED BELOW)

---

I think what you have done is located
the spatial positions in the lab frame
where the light cone of the emission event intersects

"a circle of mirrors in the rest frame of the moving observer" (what I call a circular light clock). 
Those intersections are simultaneous in the moving frame,
but not in the lab frame.

I think the spatial position of the emission event
is at one focus of your ellipse. I think the reflected light signals
with arrive at the same event whose spatial position is
at the other focus of the ellipse (in accord with the [reflective property of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Elliptical_reflectors_and_acoustics)). The ellipse is formed by the light-signals striking a moving (Lorentz-contracted) circle of mirrors... ***as if*** there was a mirror shaped like an elongated ellipse at rest in the rest frame.

You can see that in my video (in the lower "spatial diagrams", look at the set of reflections... they trace out an ellipse )
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIZeqRn7cmI
[image: robphy-Visualizing-Proper-Time]

Here is a related paper of mine

"Visualizing Proper Time in Special Relativity"
Physics Teacher (Indian Physical Society), v46 (4), pp. 132-143 (October-December 2004)
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0505134

---

Here are some other references:

James E. White
"Special Relativity and Conic Sections - A Thought Experiment" (2004)
https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/special-relativity-and-conic-sections-a-thought-experiment

William Moreau
"Wave front relativity"
American Journal of Physics 62, 426 (1994);
 https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17543

---

---

** [old] UPDATE**

Using an extension of my GeoGebra visualization of the Michelson-Morley apparatus on a spacetime diagram ( https://www.geogebra.org/m/XFXzXGTq ),
I rendered some intersections of interest.

- **Length contraction** of the longitudinal arm is required for the longitudinal echo to arrive back at the worldline at the same reception event as the transverse echo (to explain the null result of Michelson-Morley).
- For a circle of mirrors (instead of just the two interferometer arms) as in my earlier video of a **"circular light clock"**, the moving clock must be an **ellipse** (as shown in **black**) in the Lab frame.
- That **black ellipse** traces out the worldtube of the **"moving circular clock"**, which is **a circle in the moving frame** because the **(solid-lined) green ellipse** is the intersection of the the future light cone of the emission event and the worldtube of the moving clock, whose shape was determined so that the reflections return at a common reception event on the source's worldline.
  [image: robphy-MichelsonMorley-CausalDiamond-geogebra-1-withSIMplane]

[image: robphy-MichelsonMorley-CausalDiamond-geogebra-2-withPastConeOfReception]

- Thus, the **green ellipse** is (by construction to explain the null result of Michelson-Morley) the intersection of the future light cone of the emission event and the past light cone of the common reception event. **Since that is a set of radar measurements** with the same emission and reception event, the moving observer would say that **the events on the green ellipse are simultaneous and equidistant from him (from his worldline)---it is a *circular* light clock for him at an instant "at the half-tick" in the moving frame.**
- The **green ellipse** is Lorentz-boosted version of
  the reflection events at the half-tick of Lab frame's circular clock.

[image: robphy-MichelsonMorley-CausalDiamond-geogebra-3-withRadar]

- As shown in the video above, the reflection events on this **circular light clock** (the **green ellipse**) are not simultaneous in the Lab frame.
- In the Lab frame, the Lab observes an emission event at t=0 and common reception event at a later instant. Although the reflection events in the Lab frame were not simultaneous, the reflection events occurred at spatial locations in the Lab frame that trace out a **green-dashed virtual ellipse**, *as if* there was an **elliptical mirror at the rest in the Lab Frame**.

Here is the view of "space" in the Lab frame (as if time-lapsed during the duration of one tick of the moving circular light clock):

[image: robphy-MichelsonMorley-CausalDiamond-geogebra-4-spatial]

So, the **green ellipse in spacetime** is a "**circle** of reflection events marking the half-tick in the moving frame". The **dotted-green-ellipse** in space in the Lab frame
mark the spatial locations of those reflection events of the moving clock,
which occur sequentially in the Lab frame. The spatial positions in the Lab frame of the emission event and the reception event [of the moving clock] are the focal points of this dotted-green ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to follow your equations in detail, but I suspect you have made the mistake of neglecting to take the relativity of simultaneity into account in the right way. In my explanation, I will take the speed of light to be 300,000,000 m/s, which will make it easier to follow...

If you and I stand together and flash a lamp off to the left and right, the light recedes from us both at an equal speed, so that after a second it is 300,000,000 metres from us in each direction.

If we now repeat the experiment, but this time you walk after the light to the right at 1m/s, then in my frame when it is 1s everywhere the light will once again be 300,000,000m to the left and to the right. However, in your frame the light is only 299,999,999m to the right and it is 300,000,001 metres to the left, ie it is not symmetrical. The explanation is simply that in your frame the light is 300,000,000 meters to the left of me at a later time than it is 300,000,000 meters to the right of me. In your frame after a second, the light is 300,000,000 metres either side of you.

So we each think the light is 300,000,000 meters from us after 1s, and we each think the other person is not at the centre of the expanding flash of light.

Clearly, while I have described what happens when the light moves off to the left and right and you follow it to the right, the principle holds true in whichever direction the light moves from our initial common position, so we each think we are at the centre of an expanding sphere of light and that the other person isn't.

My guess is that in your modelling, you have shown that from the perspective of one observer, A, say, the other person B is not at the centre of an expanding sphere of light *in A's frame*. However, B is at the centre of the expanding sphere of light in B's frame, and it is A who is not.

You can short-cut my explanation by just considering that everyone, regardless of their state of motion, sees light receding from them at the same speed in all directions. So if you and I start together and flash a light, we will each see it receding from us in all directions at the same rate, which means each of us continues to be at the centre of a sphere in our own frame.

EDIT

I have now looked at your spreadsheet, which has confirmed my earlier suspicion. An expanding wavefront of light is spherical if all points upon it are equidistant from a common centre *at a given time*. The mistake you have made is to apply the Lorenz transform to a sphere in one frame, which unsurprisingly gives non spherical shape in the other frame because in the other frame you are considering different parts of the wavefront *at different times*. That is explicitly shown in your spreadsheet, in which your forward x' position is being viewed at a different t' to your rearward x' position.

SECOND EDIT

You still misunderstand the key concept of SR, which is that a plane of constant time in one frame is a sloping slice through time in another. Let me try to illustrate it as follows.

Suppose you and four friends are standing together, and at a given moment, t=0, your friends begin to walk away from you at 1m/s, one going north, one south, one east and one west. Now, suppose each of your friends has a GPS and is asked to send you their coordinates at one second intervals. If you plot the received coordinates, you will see a time lapsed diagram that always shows your friends to be equidistant from you, so that you are always at the centre of their movement. Do you follow that?

Now, let's suppose you repeat the experiment, but this time your friend heading east has two watches, one of which is running slow, while your friend heading west has two watches, one of which is running fast, and your friends send you two sets of readings, one based on their accurate watch and one based on their other watch. This time, when you plot the coordinates and look at the diagram, you will see that according to the readings your friends have taken with their 'correct' watches, you remain at the centre of their movement. However, if you take their faulty watches as being correct, you no longer appear at the centre of the movement of your friends, because your friend heading east will have walked further between each report of their position, on account of their watch being slow, while your friend heading west will have walked less distance between each sport of their position, on account of their watch being fast.

The centre of the motion of your four friends, according to the diagram you plot based on the faulty watches, will seem to be heading East.

So you should be able to understand from the scenario I have described that the apparent centre of the motion of the four friends depends upon what watch reading you rely upon to plot their position.

That is exactly what happens with the expanding sphere of light in reality. In the stationary frame, you view the friend heading East and the friend heading west at the same moment, and you seem to be mid-way between them. In the travelling frame, your two friends are viewed at two different moments as far as you are concerned, when one is further away and one is nearer, so the mid-point between them is somewhere else.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133121/discussion-on-answer-by-marco-ocram-does-the-transformation-of-the-spherical-wav).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the previous answers, the elliptical shape is simply the result of non-simultaneous measurement in the moving frame. However, if we measure them **simultaneously**, it will become spherical as required by Einstein. We can check this by simply showing that the rays indeed propagate at the same speed in all directions, which by definition implies that it will describe a sphere.

Let's write your spread sheet numbers for propagation on the x-axis in a more precise form:

x1' = 0.135387654494808;

t1' = 4.516046047256067e-10;

x2' = -7.386197831194043;

t2' = 2.463770396516794e-08;

In order to check if the rays are propagating with speed of light in both directions we simply compute x1'/t1' and x2'/t2', which indeed gives
$$(1)\ \frac{x_{1}'}{t_{1}'}=-\frac{x_{2}'}{t_{2}'}=299792458$$

So the speed of light is the same in both directions, thus if we measure their position **simultaneously**, they obviously have traversed the same distance, satisfying the spherical wave condition.

Now, for the rays in the y-direction we have:

y1 = y1' = 1;

y2 = y2' = -1;

t3' = 1.254465428494677e-08;

Since the ray propagates vertically in the first frame, it is inclined in the other frame according to the Pythagorean theorem:
$$y_{1}^{\prime2}+v^{2}t_{3}^{\prime2}=(-y_{2})^{\prime2}+v^{2}t_{3}^{\prime2}=1+v^{2}t_{3}^{\prime2}=14.14356205463129$$

which is identical to
$$c^{2}t_{3}^{\prime2}=14.14356205463129$$
thus
$$(2)\ \sqrt{\frac{1+v^{2}t_{3}^{\prime2}}{t_{3}^{\prime2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{c^{2}t_{3}^{\prime2}}{t_{3}^{\prime2}}}=299792458$$

By equations (1) and (2), all rays propagate at the speed of light in any direction, thus when measured **simultaneously**, they form a sphere.

Comment: “As explained in the previous answers, the elliptical shape is simply the result of non-simultaneous measurement in the moving frame.”,
Einstein claims that the transformed equations result in a spherical wave, which requires that all points on the wave are the same distance from the centre at the same time. For an ellipse this is obviously not the case!

Comment: “However, if we measure them simultaneously, it will become spherical as required by Einstein.”,

As far as I know, the only way you can measure them simultaneously is by performing an inverse Lorentz Transformation? But then you are back to the untransformed equations in the stationary frame?

Comment: “We can check this by simply showing that the rays indeed propagate at the same speed in all directions, which by definition implies that it will describe a sphere”,
Another simple way to see this is that you have length contraction in the x axis and time dilation (Tau) by the factor gamma. Hence the distance decreases and the time decreases, implying a constant speed.
But this is not a wave that is spherical in shape, it is an ellipsoidal wave that propagates with speed c!

Answer (score -1):

The following claim is made:

“The light forms a sphere at any fixed value of tau. It also forms a sphere at any fixed value of t. “,

How can a sphere transform to a sphere? Simple logic tells us it is impossible, a sphere transforms to an ellipsoid!

It is easy to show the fallacy of the argument based on freezing time t’=Tau:

1. Assume for the moment that we get a sphere at a single instant of time t’=Tau.
2. Then it must be true that we also get a (slightly larger) sphere at time t’+dt’ (with dt’ an arbitrary small time increment).
3. Hence it must be true that we also get a (still larger) sphere at time t’+kdt’ (with dt’ an arbitrary small time increment and k an integer)
4. Hence we conclude that we must get a sphere for all time t’ if we make dt’ small enough and k large enough!
5. Now we make a scatterplot of y’ versus x’ for all time t’.
6. The scatterplot shows a (filled in solid) ellipse, not a circle!
7. Hence we obtain a contradiction with our original assumption of a circle for an instant of time t’! So the assumption that we get a sphere at a single instant of time t’=Tau is clearly FALSE!

So the above conclusively shows that you cannot get a sphere by restricting t’=Tau, as you claim! If you get a sphere for a single instant of time t’, then you must get spheres for all time t’ (hence also for all time t in the untransformed equations)! A simple scatterplot of y’ versus x’ shows the assumption of a circle is indeed false, an ellipse (not circle) is obtained!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133514/discussion-between-marco-ocram-and-piet-venter).

Answer (score -3):

Einstein in his 1905 paper was not content to simply say “…is no less an ellipsoidal wave with velocity of propagation c when viewed in the moving system”.

Einstein have indeed set a high bar by saying “…is no less a spherical wave”! It goes against every physical intuition we have. Einstein must therefore prove that the transformed equations produce a spherical wave. Unfortunately Einstein only shows that  the transformed equations satisfy a spherical wave equation! It does not prove that the transformed equations produce a spherical shape.

From the answers to the question some definitions of a spherical wave are:

Definition 1: “Light will however, be a sphere if viewed at a single instant of time in B's frame”,

Definition 2: “An expanding wavefront of light is spherical if all points upon it are equidistant from a common centre at a given time.”,

If we take definition 2 for the moment, then we can take a single instant of time t in the original (untransformed equations) and test whether x,y and z is a sphere. To do this we need to:

1. Determine the centre of the datapoints at time t
2. Determine the distance from the centre of the datapoints
3. Check that each distance from the centre is the same
   When we perform the above 3 steps on the untransformed datapoints (say in a spreadsheet) it is clear that we have a spherical wave.
   Another simple way to test for a sphere is to make scatterplots of y versus x etc. and then visually see if we have circles for each instant of time t.

Now we proceed to the difficult case of the moving observer. Suppose we take definition 2 as basis and apply the 3 steps first to a single sphere at time t, which we transform using the Lorentz Transformation:

1. Determine the centre of the datapoints at time t’=Tau. Immediately there is a big problem! The original single  sphere (of the spherical wave) at time t is transformed into a multitude of datapoints at different times, due to the relativity of simultaneity. At each instant of time t’=Tau we have just a few datapoints! So how can we determine a centre with just one or datapoints? It is statistically invalid to fit a few datapoints to a circle (a straight line approximation would be better as it involves fewer assumptions).

As the idea of fitting a sphere to a single instant of time t’=Tau fails, how about using a range of values of t’=Tau? For example, in a spreadsheet we can use Tau_min<t’<Tau_max to select a range of values for t’=Tau (we can make the range as small or as large as we want).

If we use a range large enough to capture all the transformed time values t’=Tau for a single (untransformed) sphere at time t, then we will find eg. from a scatterplot of y’ versus x’ that we do NOT have a spherical wave, but rather an ellipsoidal wave!
Obviously we could also have used the more laborious 3 step procedure to test if the transformed datapoints satisfy a spherical shape.

I have placed some screenshots from the spreadsheet with t’=Tau frozen in time (for a range of Tau_min to Tau_max) at: https://bit.ly/32D9D1T  It is clear from the screenshots that a scatterplot of y’ versus x’ does not generally produce a sphere!

The spreadsheet can be found here: https://bit.ly/3Hp5pd3

Hence it is clear that freezing the transformed equations in time t’=Tau cannot produce a sphere! Hence the claim by Einstein that a spherical wave is produced is wrong. Einstein should have said: “…is no less an ellipsoidal wave with velocity of propagation c when viewed in the moving system”.

[EDIT]

In the spreadsheet I have tried freezing t’=Tau at a single instant (Tau=1.40102e-8):

https://bit.ly/3tkagZk

As you can see from the screenshot above, only a single datapoint is returned!
So one needs to consider a range of values around t’=Tau (Tau_min<t’<Tau_max) in order to make a scatterplot with enough datapoints for analysis.

[EDIT 2]

In response to a claim that the relativity of simultaneity allows one to observe a sphere;

“The light forms a sphere at any fixed value of tau. “,

I can simply show you why you won’t find a circle:

Let $K_{\tau}$ be a single arbitrary fixed point in time corresponding to $t’=\tau$:

$ \\ \xi=x-vt \\$

$ \\ \tau=t’= t-v/c^2 x \\$

$ \\ K_{\tau}=t-(v/c)t =(1-v/c)t \\ $

$\\ t=K_{\tau}/(1-v/c) \\ $

$\\ \xi= \gamma (x-vt) \\ $

$\\= \gamma (c-v)t \\ $

$ \\=\gamma (c-v)K_{\tau}/(1-v/c) \\ $

$ \\ \xi =  \gamma cK_{\tau} \\ $

Now examine y’:
$ \\ y’=y=ct=cK_{\tau}/(1-v/c) \\ $

$ \\ y’=y=K_{\tau}/(c-v) \\ $

As you can see from above, $\xi =x’ <> y’$, so there can be no sphere at an instant of time $K_{\tau}$!

“The light forms a sphere at any fixed value of tau. It also forms a sphere at any fixed value of t. “,

How can a sphere transform to a sphere? Simple logic tells us it is impossible, a sphere transforms to an ellipsoidal wave!

It is easy to show the fallacy of the argument based on freezing time t’=Tau:

1. Assume for the moment that we get a sphere at a single instant of time t’=Tau.
2. Then it must be true that we also get a (slightly larger) sphere at time t’+dt’ (with dt’ an arbitrary small time increment).
3. Hence it must be true that we also get a (still larger) sphere at time t’+kdt’ (with dt’ an arbitrary small time increment and k an integer)
4. Hence we conclude that we must get a sphere for all time t’ if we make dt’ small enough and k large enough!
5. Now we make a scatterplot of y’ versus x’ for all time t’.
6. The scatterplot shows a (filled in solid) ellipse, not a circle!
7. Hence we obtain a contradiction with our original assumption of a circle for an instant of time t’! So the assumption that we get a sphere at a single instant of time t’=Tau is clearly FALSE!

So the above conclusively shows that you cannot get a sphere by restricting t’=Tau, as you claim! If you get a sphere for a single instant of time t’, then you must get spheres for all time t’ (hence also for all time t in the untransformed equations)! A simple scatterplot of y’ versus x’ shows the assumption of a circle is indeed false, an ellipse (not circle) is obtained!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133218/discussion-on-answer-by-piet-venter-does-the-transformation-of-the-spherical-wav).

Comment: “The light forms a sphere at any fixed value of tau. It also forms a sphere at any fixed value of t. “,

How can a sphere transform to a sphere? Simple logic tells us it is impossible, a sphere transforms to an ellipsoidal wave!

It is easy to show the fallacy of the argument based on freezing time t’=Tau:
1. Assume for the moment that we get a sphere at a single instant of time t’=Tau.
2. Then it must be true that we also get a (slightly larger) sphere at time t’+dt’ (with dt’ an arbitrary small time increment). ………

Comment: ……. 3. Hence it must be true that we also get a (still larger) sphere at time t’+kdt’ (with dt’ an arbitrary small time increment and k an integer)
4. Hence we conclude that we must get a sphere for all time t’ if we make dt’ small enough and k large enough!
5. Now we make a scatterplot of y’ versus x’ for all time t’.
6. The scatterplot shows a (filled in solid) ellipse, not a circle! ………

Comment: …….. 7. Hence we obtain a contradiction with our original assumption of a circle for an instant of time t’! So the assumption that we get a sphere at a single instant of time t’=Tau is clearly FALSE!

So the above conclusively shows that you cannot get a sphere by restricting t’=Tau, as you claim! If you get a sphere for a single instant of time t’, then you must get spheres for all time t’ (hence also for all time t in the untransformed equations)! A simple scatterplot of y’ versus x’ shows the assumption of a circle is indeed false, an ellipse (not circle) is obtained!